How to implement scroll bar in multilevel dropdown menus parent and child menus both?
I want to apply the scrollbar in my parent and child dropdowns, my dropdown menus contain a lot of options for that scrollbar is mandatory, How can I do that?
Here is the reference image:
dropdown-image
Here is the reference fiddle code , I want to apply scrollbar in both menu "https://jsfiddle.net/Nimra/ap7mhskn/4/"
I've experimented with various options, but I can only achieve a single scrollbar at a time, either in the parent or the child. In contrast, I require both to have their scrollbars simultaneously.

I solved this by using @angular/cdk portals and overlay like this. When javascript is disabled, you can't do this, so in that case I just show the submenus inline

@ whoever cast a close-vote to this question, you've been reported to the SO admins

@pieterjan how to cast close vote ?
